# Find most recent record in a subquery (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, sql-order-by

I'm converting some code from Oracle to SQL Server (2012) and have run into an issue where this subquery is using a PARTITION/ORDER BY to retrieve the most recent record. The subquery runs fine on its own, but as it is a subquery, I'm getting the error:

> SQL Server Database Error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views,
>   inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table
>   expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Here's the section of SQL:

```
FROM (
  SELECT distinct enr.MemberNum,
    (ISNULL(enr.MemberFirstName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(enr.MemberLastName, '')) AS MEMBER_NAME,
    enr.MemberBirthDate as DOB,
    enr.MemberGender as Gender,
    LAST_VALUE(enr.MemberCurrentAge) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberNum ORDER BY StaticDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS AGE,
    LAST_VALUE(enr.EligStateAidCategory)OVER (PARTITION BY MemberNum ORDER BY StaticDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS EligStateAidCategory,
    LAST_VALUE(enr.EligStateAidCategory)OVER (PARTITION BY MemberNum ORDER BY StaticDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS AID_CAT_ROLL_UP,
    LAST_VALUE(enr.EligFinanceAidCategoryRollup)OVER (PARTITION BY MemberNum ORDER BY StaticDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS EligFinanceAidCategoryRollup,
    SUM(enr.MemberMonth) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberNum) AS TOTAL_MEMBER_MONTHS
  FROM dv_Enrollment enr
  WHERE enr.StaticDate BETWEEN '01-JUN-2016' AND '30-JUN-2016'
)A
```

So, I've looked around and found that you can use the TOP (2147483647) hack, so I tried changing the first line to:

```
SELECT distinct TOP (2147483647) enr.MemberNum,
```

But I'm still getting the same error. All the other ways I've thought of also require an ORDER BY (using DENSE RANK, etc).

Comment: i don't see an `order by` in the sub-query. can you post the full query text?

Comment: you're missing an H in `wHere`

Comment: be careful with `between` [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand - 2009-10-16](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: The my editor's (TOAD) error pane is pointing the message to the ORDER BY in what would be row 6 there:
LAST_VALUE(enr.MemberCurrentAge) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberNum ORDER BY StaticDate

Comment: @SqlZim, oops,I introduce that in my copy/paste.

Comment: @SqlZim. 2012. Thanks, added that up top to the original question.

Comment: This error should not apply to what's inside the `over` clause. [can't even repro in rextester.](http://rextester.com/XIRKI43786)

Comment: Why are `EligStateAidCategory` and `AID_CAT_ROLL_UP` the same thing?

Comment: You're using TOAD to develop queries in SQL Server? What happens if you run the query in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both databases, I would write this like:

```
FROM (SELECT enr.MemberNum,
             (ISNULL(enr.MemberFirstName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(enr.MemberLastName, '')) AS MEMBER_NAME,
             enr.MemberBirthDate as DOB,
             enr.MemberGender as Gender,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN enr.MemberCurrentAge END) AS AGE,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN enr.EligStateAidCategory END) AS EligStateAidCategory,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN enr.EligStateAidCategory END) AS AID_CAT_ROLL_UP,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN enr.EligFinanceAidCategoryRollup END) AS EligFinanceAidCategoryRollup,
            SUM(enr.MemberMonth) as TOTAL_MEMBER_MONTHS
    FROM (SELECT enr.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberNum ORDER BY StaticDate DESC) as seqnum
          FROM dv_Enrollment enr
         ) enr
    WHERE enr.StaticDate >= DATE '2016-06-01' AND  -- DATE not needed in SQL Server
          enr.StaticDate < DATE '2016-07-01'       -- DATE not needed in SQL Server
    GROUP BY enr.MemberNum, enr.MemberFirstName, enr.MemberLastName,
             enr.MemberBirthDate, enr.MemberGender
   ) A
```

Why the changes?

- The date changes are just to be careful about time components on the date.  `BETWEEN` with date/times is a bad habit, because sometimes it can result in incorrect code and hard to debug errors.
- I simply do not like using `SELECT DISTINCT` to mean `GROUP BY`.  It is clever to use it with window functions (and necessary with `LAST_VALUE())`; but I think the code ends up being misleading.
- I find the use of the subquery with `seqnum` to make it clear that the four "last value" variables are all pulling data from the last row.
- In addition, it the sort is not stable (that is, the key is not unique), `seqnum` guarantees that the values are all from the same row.  `last_value()` does not.

Comment: Very nice, much less to rewrite compared to my approach. +1

Answer (score 0):

Switch this over to an aggregate subquery and [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) and see what happens.

```
select 
    e.MemberNum
  , e.MemberName
  , e.DOB
  , e.Gender
  , x.MemberCurrentAge
  , x.EligStateAidCategory
  , x.EligFinanceAidCategoryRollup
  , x.MemberMonth
  , e.Total_Member_Months
from (
    select
        enr.MemberNum
      , MemberName = isnull(enr.MemberFirstName+' ', '') + isnull(enr.MemberLastName, '')
      , DOB    = enr.MemberBirthDate
      , Gender = enr.MemberGender
      /* This sounds like a weird thing to sum */
      , Total_Member_Months = sum(enr.MemberMonth) 
    from dv_Enrollment enr
    group by 
        enr.MemberNum
      , isnull(enr.MemberFirstName+' ', '') + isnull(enr.MemberLastName, '')
      , enr.MemberBirthDate
      , enr.MemberGender
    ) as e
  /* cross apply() is like an inner join
   , use outer apply() for something like a left join */
  cross apply (
    select top 1
        i.MemberCurrentAge
      , i.EligStateAidCategory
      , i.EligFinanceAidCategoryRollup
      , i.MemberMonth
      from dv_Enrollment as i
      where i.MemberNum = e.MemberNum
        and i.StaticDate >= '20160601'
        and i.StatisDate <= '20160630'
      order by i.StaticDate desc -- descending for most recent
    ) as x
```